# Modifying an R package with GPL-2 | GPL-3. What is the correct workflow?

Tags: gpl-3, gpl-2, package

I made a modification of the [R package rpart](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/index.html) for researching purposes. The license is GPL-2 | GPL-3.

The modification is simple but it is critical for another package that I have developed. I would like to upload it to Github for reproducibility purposes.

I have two questions:

- How should I acknowledge the authors of rpart? Is a forking in github enough? Can I include myself as an author?
- Am I obliged to use GPL license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should maintain their copyright notices intact; this is required by eg [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html) s4.  You can do this by forking their repository, or copying it to another git hosting service, or publishing tarballs; the GPL doesn't care about *how* you preserve them.  As for acknowledging yourself, you should *add* a copyright notice of your own.
2. Yes.  GPLv3 s5c says you may convey "*a work based on the Program*" but you "*must license the entire work, as a whole, under this License to anyone who comes into possession of a copy*".  GPLv2 has comparable language.